# how to display only time in Index List in Asp.net mVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime

i have a List of Start Time and Time and i only want Time but it show with date

**Model**

```
    public DateTime Starttime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
```

**Viewe**

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        <tr>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Starttime)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndTime)
                            </td>
                            @if (item.Status == 1)
                            {
                                <td>
                                    <p>Avaliable</p>
                                </td>
                            }
                            @if (item.Status == 2)
                            {
                                <td>
                                    <p>Cancel</p>
                                </td>
                            }

                        </tr>
                    }
                }
```

its show me this result 
[OutPut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYasf.png)

But i need this format it is possible ??
[i want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Aztr.png)

its my First question on StatkOverFlow

Comment: Use `TimeSpan`, not `DateTime` (or add a `[DisplayFormat]` attribute to your properties to display only the time)

Comment: Just remove this `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndTime) ` and use `item .ToShortTimeString()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke it also worked Thanks :)

Comment: @zubairzubairgone you should look at Stephen comment too. After rechecking your question `TimeSpan` is the best practice here.

Comment: I am not 100% sure I agree that `TimeSpan` is the best practice here @CodeNotFound . `TimeSpan` represents a time **period / interval** . A time of day represents a **point** in time. If anything, I'd suggest NodaTime's `LocalTime` - https://nodatime.org/2.3.x/api/NodaTime.LocalTime.html .